# notepad++ changes cursor position while typing

Tags: notepad++

When I'm typing in Notepad++, the cursor sometimes jumps to another position, causing me to unintentionally overwrite other text. This occurs with Notepad++ v5.7 and v5.9 (and possibly older versions) in Windows XP SP3. Does anyone know a workaround until this bug gets fixed?

**EDIT:** Yes, I'm using a laptop, but it's docked. I'm using an external keyboard. This cursor jumping only happens with Notepad++. It doesn't seem to occur with any particular key sequence (that I've noticed). I don't know if this matters, but I'm typing in a Lua file. I haven't tested for the bug in other file types.

Comment: Is this on a laptop?

Comment: I use Notepad++ 5.8.7 and have not seen this problem. However, I have had issues with the touchpad on my laptop being extra-sensitive and considering even the lightest brush of my thumb to be a mouse click, thus changing the cursor's position. Extremely frustrating. Could that be happening for you? (I know it sounds too simple, but just asking...)

Comment: Happened to me too :) very annoying

Comment: @TuxRug, Yes, but I'm using an external keyboard.

Comment: I'm not using the touchpad or any other mouse control on my laptop, since I'm using my external keyboard. I know what you're talking about though. I've had the same problem with the touchpad, but I fixed that particular problem by adjusting the touchpad sensitivity.

Comment: Try deactivating the touchpad completely. Also, do you have a synergy client running?

Comment: @bitmask, deactivating touchpad didn't help. I don't have a synergy client. I've just noticed that it happens only when I have code blocks folded. The cursor randomly jumps into the code fold as I'm typing. I guess a workaround is not use code folding.

Comment: This is happening to me too! So frustrating. I'm on a desktop, no touchpad. It has to do with the caps lock key. Here's a bug report filed 2009: http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/2288/ :-/

Comment: upgrade os? get a faster pc? never had this issue on mine. win 7 x64 ultrafast pc.